# Using initializers to set all bounds of a multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

Why doesn't this compile? I don't want to put `2` in the last pair of brackets. Is there another way to do it?

```
int ary[][] = {{2, 3}, {5, 7}, {11, 13}};
```

Comment: Because the language requires you to specify all dimensions except the first, there's no way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it without specifying the dimensions, using compound literals:

```
int* ary[] = {( int[] ){2, 3}, ( int[] ){5, 7}, ( int[] ){11, 13} };
```

And the usage stays the same!:

```
ary[2][1] = 55 ;
printf("%d %d\n" , ary[2][0] , ary[2][1] ) ;
```

Compound literals have the same scope and lifetime as the array `ary`, so this is very similar as using a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
int ary[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
```

Now it is up to you to index the array appropriately.  You must know somewhere that the number of elements per "row" is 2, so just do this:

```
int* get_cell(int* arr, size_t N, size_t x, size_t y)
{
  return &arr[x + N * y];
}
```